# How does Scala's equals method work in the case of a List?

Tags: list, scala, equals

```
list1 == list2
```

To do the above check, will Scala iterate through both lists and call equals on each pair of elements ?

(I am sure, this question has been asked before, but I could not find a good answer with Google & Co)

Comment: Have you looked at the code? Scala is open source.

Comment: @Tyler: Yes, but I could not find the correct piec of code, since List extends a lot of other classes.

Comment: @Denis: Yes, and it seems to work like I said, but I want to be sure that my tests are the rule, not the exception

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can find this out yourself for any method by looking at the Scaladoc and finding out where it's defined, and then looking at the source.  If you start with the [online docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html), you can do this all just with clicking: go to the method, open it up by clicking on the arrow on the left, and you'll see a list of overriding classes.  Go to the first one, and look at the source.

Anyway, in this case, `GenSeqLike`, a supertrait of `List` and many other collections, defines `equals` as a `canEqual` check followed by `sameElements`.  In turn, `sameElements` checks whether both arguments are `LinearSeq`s, and if so, calls equals on each pair of elements by splitting the head and tail apart one by one.  Otherwise it defaults to using iterators, calling `hasNext` on each and then comparing the elements with `equals`.

So, long story short: yes, it calls equals on each pair of elements (stopping as soon as it finds a mismatch).

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. That helped a lot (also for future researches).