# Matchers eq incorrectly saying lists are not equal

Tags: scala, mockito

I'm writing some scala tests and have

```
when(mockLoader.load(Matchers.eq(expectedPath))).thenReturn(testData)
val data = mockLoader.load(expectedPath)
data.count() shouldBe 0
```

but I get NPE on performing count() on data, meaning the mock thinks I put in an unexpected path. This is expectedPath:

```
val expectedPath = List("hdfs:///session/stream/folder/100")
```

When I println the path that mockito expects and the path that my code actually generates, I see

```
[scalatest] path made is: List("hdfs:///session/stream/folder/100")
[scalatest] mock path is: List("hdfs:///session/stream/folder/100")
```

is there some kind of internal comparison that Matchers computes that would fail lists that contain identical values?

Comment: Why do you even need a `Matchers.eq`?

Comment: There are other parameters in mockLoader.load that use Matchers.eq that I omitted as they are just unnecessary details. I know the other parameters don't have any impact on this test because the test was passing beforehand and only started failing once I made expectedPath a List

Comment: update: out of curiosity I tried getting rid of matchers and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you confirm that `Loader` and `load` are `open` (or, better, paste them into your question) and confirm or show how you initialize `testData`?

Comment: when I replace Matchers.eq(expectedPath) with any() then testData is returned and my test passes. This definitely suggests that an unexpected path is seen by Mockito

Comment: @XinWenyu That helps, thanks. Is it possible that the path is a Uri in one case and a String in the other? Or that they might otherwise be different types? [Matchers delegates to the normal Java `equals` method](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.22.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers), and [Scala does test list items for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11123393/1426891), so the only thing I'm left to think is that the List contents are different types with the same `toString` value.

Answer (score 1):

Try using mockito-scala, it will help you in different ways

- If you use it in strict mode (by mixing in the mockito fixture) it will fail fast if your code calls the mock with values different than the ones you stubbed
- Don't need to do Matchers.eq as the matcher has been renamed to eqTo
- eqTo uses scalactic equality, so you can even go and override how those objects are being compared
- You only need to provide matchers for the parameters that require them (when using the idiomatic syntax, the compiler will automatically wrap the rest with eqTo)

Check https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala for a more detailed description of those features

Hope it helps!